# Manual override for spring scheduler (using annotations)

Tags: java, web-services, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, spring-ws

I have a spring ws client where i have scheduled my services to run the client using annotations @Scheduled .
How can i provide a manual override so that i can start and stop the service in between whenever necessary ?

Comment: Well you should maybe implement a flag in the database and each time your scheduled method starts, they check if the flag is true or false

Comment: @Amine thanks a lot for the reply ...ended up using the same approach u suggested